# CMake shared library from object library & DLL exports

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries

## Background

I use cmake to build an [open-source library](https://github.com/simulton/gpds).

The project is setup to do the following:

- Build a cmake `OBJECT` library named `gpds-objs`
- Build a `STATIC` library named `gpds-static` from `gpds-objs`
- Build a `SHARED` library named `gpds-shared` from `gpds-objs`

Furthermore, I'm using cmake's `generate_export_header()` to generate the necessary export macros.

The relevant parts of the cmake script looks like this:

```
# Set project information
project(gpds
    VERSION 1.0.0
    LANGUAGES CXX
    HOMEPAGE_URL "https://gpds.simulton.com"
)

# Some bacis cmake configuration
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR_IN_INTERFACE ON)

# List of private source files
set(SOURCES_PRIVATE
    # ...
)

# List of private header files
set(HEADERS_PRIVATE
    # ...
)

# List of public header files
set(HEADERS_PUBLIC
    # ...
)

# Define targets
set(NAME gpds)
set(TARGET-OBJS   ${NAME}-objs)
set(TARGET-STATIC ${NAME}-static)
set(TARGET-SHARED ${NAME}-shared)


################################################################################
# Object library                                                               #
################################################################################

add_library(${TARGET-OBJS} OBJECT)

target_compile_features(
    gpds-objs
    PUBLIC
        cxx_std_17
)

target_sources(
    ${TARGET-OBJS}
    PRIVATE
        ${SOURCES_PRIVATE}
        ${HEADERS_PRIVATE}
)

target_include_directories(
    ${TARGET-OBJS}
    INTERFACE
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include>
    PRIVATE
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include/gpds>
)


################################################################################
# Shared library                                                               #
################################################################################

add_library(${TARGET-SHARED} SHARED)

target_link_libraries(
    ${TARGET-SHARED}
    PUBLIC
        gpds-objs
)

target_compile_definitions(
    ${TARGET-SHARED}
    PRIVATE
        gpds_shared_EXPORTS     # We're building this library!
)


################################################################################
# Static library                                                               #
################################################################################

add_library(${TARGET-STATIC} STATIC)

target_link_libraries(
    ${TARGET-STATIC}
    PUBLIC
        gpds-objs
)

target_compile_definitions(
    ${TARGET-STATIC}
    PUBLIC
        GPDS_STATIC_DEFINE
)

# Common library properties
set_target_properties(
    ${TARGET-OBJS}
    ${TARGET-STATIC}
    ${TARGET-SHARED}
    PROPERTIES
        OUTPUT_NAME "gpds"
        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_NAME "gpds"
        VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
        POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE 1
)



################################################################################
# Export header                                                                #
################################################################################

include(GenerateExportHeader)
generate_export_header(
    ${TARGET-SHARED}
    BASE_NAME gpds
    EXPORT_FILE_NAME gpds_export.hpp
    DEPRECATED_MACRO_NAME "GPDS_DEPRECATED"
    NO_DEPRECATED_MACRO_NAME "GPDS_NO_DEPRECATED"
    EXPORT_MACRO_NAME "GPDS_EXPORT"
    NO_EXPORT_MACRO_NAME "GPDS_NO_EXPORT"
    STATIC_DEFINE "GPDS_STATIC_DEFINE"
    DEFINE_NO_DEPRECATED
)
```

A class definition within the library looks like this:

```cpp
#include "gpds_export.hpp"

namespace gpds
{
    class GPDS_EXPORT container
    {
        // ...
    };
}
```

For completeness, here's the relevant part of `gpds_export.hpp` which gets generated by cmake's `generate_export_header()`:

```cpp
#ifdef GPDS_STATIC_DEFINE
#  define GPDS_EXPORT
#  define GPDS_NO_EXPORT
#else
#  ifndef GPDS_EXPORT
#    ifdef gpds_shared_EXPORTS
        /* We are building this library */
#      define GPDS_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#    else
        /* We are using this library */
#      define GPDS_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#    endif
#  endif

#  ifndef GPDS_NO_EXPORT
#    define GPDS_NO_EXPORT 
#  endif
#endif
```

## The problem

The problem I'm running into is when building `gpds-objs` I am presented with the following messages:

```
C:\Users\joel\Documents\projects\gpds\lib\src\value.cpp:7:1: warning: 'gpds::value::value(const gpds::value&)' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
    7 | value::value(const value& other) :
      | ^~~~~
C:\Users\joel\Documents\projects\gpds\lib\src\value.cpp:17:1: warning: 'gpds::value::value(gpds::value&&)' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
   17 | value::value(value&& other) :
      | ^~~~~
C:\Users\joel\Documents\projects\gpds\lib\src\value.cpp:25:1: warning: 'virtual gpds::value::~value()' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
   25 | value::~value() noexcept
      | ^~~~~
C:\Users\joel\Documents\projects\gpds\lib\src\value.cpp:33:6: warning: 'void gpds::value::from_string(std::string&&)' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
   33 | void value::from_string(std::string&& string)
```

I am unsure how to solve this properly.

From what I understand the problem is that building the `gpds-objs` target does not define any of the relevant export macros (neither `GPDS_STATIC_DEFINE` nor `gpds_shared_EXPORTS`). Therefore, `GPDS_EXPORT` gets defined to `__declspec(dllimport)` which is incorrect as we're not building a shared library with the `gpds-objs` target.

One solution I can think of is defining `gpds_shared_EXPORTS` on the `gpds-objs` target instead of the `gpds-shared` target. However, this would mean that it's also defined when building the `gpds-static` target. This might be fine as long as `gpds-static` defines `GPDS_STATIC_DEFINE`.

What is the correct way of handling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot** use the same OBJECT library both for shared and static libraries.

An OBJECT library determines how the source files should be compiled.
But source files should be **compiled differently** for a static and for a shared libraries.

[Documentation for GenerateExportHeader](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GenerateExportHeader.html) describes, how the same generated header file could be used for static and shared libraries:

```cmake
add_library(shared_variant SHARED ${lib_SRCS})
add_library(static_variant ${lib_SRCS})
generate_export_header(shared_variant BASE_NAME libshared_and_static)
set_target_properties(static_variant PROPERTIES
  COMPILE_FLAGS -DLIBSHARED_AND_STATIC_STATIC_DEFINE)
```

Here the export header is generated for the **shared library**, and the *static* library has additional compile definition for reuse that header.
Note again, that different compile options, used for shared and static libraries, mean that you cannot reuse **object** files between these libraries. You could only reuse **sources**.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why one cannot use the same `OBJECT` library for building a `STATIC` and a `SHARED` library? I believe I have seen this pattern somewhere in an official cmake guide (might have been inofficial tho).
You mention that the sources get compiled differently - Would love to know more about that.

Comment: "You mention that the sources get compiled differently - Would love to know more about that." - In the code which I cited in the question post, the target `static_variant` has specific compile definition and the target `shared_variant` doesn't have it. That mean that targets are compiled differently. What else do you want to know?

Comment: I looked into it - you're absolutely right. Thanks!