# CMake Add additional DLL Target and link it to the static target

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following Project Structure:

```
\---mwe
    |   CMakeLists.txt
    +---app
    |       CMakeLists.txt
    |       main.cpp
    +---include
    |   \---mwe
    |           export.hpp
    |           my_lib.hpp
    \---src
            dummy.cpp
            example_class.cpp
            example_class.hpp
            my_lib.cpp
```

I have the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

if(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Do not build in-source. Please remove CMakeCache.txt and the CMakeFiles/ directory. Then build out-of-source.")
endif()

project("mwe" VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build shared (dynamic) libraries." ON)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_static STATIC include/${PROJECT_NAME}/export.hpp include/${PROJECT_NAME}/my_lib.hpp src/example_class.hpp src/example_class.cpp src/my_lib.cpp)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}_static  PUBLIC "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>"
                            "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:$<INSTALL_PREFIX>/${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>"
                            PRIVATE "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src>") 
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_static PROPERTIES VERSION ${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION}
                        PUBLIC_HEADER "${${LIBRARY_NAME}_HDR}")
string (TOUPPER ${PROJECT_NAME} PROJECT_NAME_UPPER)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_static PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -D${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}_STATIC)

if (MSVC)
    set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_static PROPERTIES DEBUG_POSTFIX "d")
endif()

include(GenerateExportHeader)
string (TOUPPER ${PROJECT_NAME} PROJECT_NAME_UPPER)
generate_export_header(${PROJECT_NAME}_static
    EXPORT_FILE_NAME ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/${PROJECT_NAME}/export.hpp
    EXPORT_MACRO_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}_EXPORT
    STATIC_DEFINE ${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}_STATIC
)


add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED src/dummy.cpp)

add_library("Mwe::mwe" ALIAS ${PROJECT_NAME})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${PROJECT_NAME}_static)

add_subdirectory(app)
```

And the `CMakeLists.txt` in the `app` folder:

```
set(APP_TARGET_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME}_app)

add_executable(${APP_TARGET_NAME} main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${APP_TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE Mwe::mwe)
```

I first create a `static` library from all the sources of the Project.
I want to link to this `static` library for my tests that i'm able to test also the private Part of the Library. (the function/classes which i don't want to export)

For the application i want to link to a `shared` Library. Thats what the second Target is creating. Since i could not create a `shared` Library without specifing the `sources` i added an empty `dummy.cpp` file. I then link that `shared` Library to the previously created `static` one.

The creation of both works quite well. But if i build the whole Project it gave me the following error when it tries to link the `main.cpp` with the `dll` :

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: Datei "..\Debug\mwe.lib" kann nicht geöffnet werden. [D:\projekte\mwe\build\app\mwe_app.vcxproj]

Comment: "I then link that `shared` Library to the previously created `static` one." - No, this doesn't work. You cannot reuse source files, compiled in a "static" variant (that is, without exporting symbols) in a shared library, which requires exporting symbols. You need to define you shared library and list all source files. See that [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67536362/3440745) to the similar question, which attempted to link same OBJECT library into both static and shared one.

Comment: BTW, the reason of the error message you got is exactly absence of exported symbols. See e.g. that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40739061/error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-debug-myprojectlib-lib

Comment: @Tsyvarev ok so i have to build the shared also from the source files. Then i don't need to link it to the static library i guess and only link my test target to the static library